# Propensity score for a multinomial treatment to be used in a propensity score adjusted glm

Tags: r, multinomial, propensity-score-matching

I have never used propensity scores for mulitnomial variables, and so I am unfamiliar with how the predicted probabilities are handled. I have a factor variable for treatment with 5 categories and I calculated a propensity score using multinom()

`PSmod<- multinom(Treat~Age+BMI+Gender+Smoking+HIV,data =df)`

`df$PS <- predict(PSmod, type = 'probs')`

This gives me a variable of which the class is "matrix" "array" and I am not sure how to work with this. How can I obtain a single probability from this matrix array for each subject so that I can model a glm adjusting for their propensity score?
Thanks

Comment: Next time it would be helpful to provide the `dput` of your data or use this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. Adjusting for the propensity score is very complicated with multicategory treatments. Instead, use the propensity to form inverse probability weights and fit an outcome regression model to the weighted sample. To estimate the ATE, you compute each unit's weight as the inverse of the probability of being in the group they are in. The way you would create these weights in R is the following:

```
for (i in 1:nlevels(df$Treat)) {
  in_i <- which(df$Treat == levels(df$Treat)[i])
  df$weight[in_i] <- 1/PS_mat[in_i, i]
}
```

Or, you can just use the `WeightIt` package. `WeightIt` offers the function `get_w_from_ps()`, which takes in the PS matrix and the treatment vector and returns the weights. Even better would be to use `weightit()` to estimate the weights in a single step using one of a variety of methods, including but not limited to multinomial logistic regression. Other available methods include machine learning-based methods, optimization-based methods, and other generalized linear models beyond logistic. See my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401575/iptw-for-multiple-treatments/401715#401715) for an example.

Comment: ok thanks I looked at the weightit() function, and I think this may work for me, this is very helpful